# Update database in foreach loop

Tags: express, mongoose

When I run this code

```js
router.post('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const{ truckDriver, truckNumber, admin, customer, loadPlanning } = req.body;
        await User.find({isVerified: true}, function(err,data){
            adminArray = data;
            for(var key in req.body) {
                if(req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    adminArray.forEach(function(data){
                        if(truckDriver == data.email){
                            console.log(truckDriver);
                            User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {truckDriver: true});
                        }
                        if(truckNumber == data.email){
                            console.log(truckNumber);
                            User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {truckNumber: truckNumber});
                        }
                        if(admin == data.email){
                            console.log(admin);
                            User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {admin: true});
                        }
                        if(customer == data.email){
                            console.log(customer);
                            User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {customer: true});
                        }
                        if(loadPlanning == data.email){
                            console.log(loadPlanning);
                            User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {loadPlanning: true});
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        })
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Your accounts have been processed!');
        res.redirect('/admin');
    }
    catch (e){
        res.send('error_msg');
        console.log(e);
    };
});
```

The console.log will output the user's email, but the user accounts do not get updated. What could I be doing wrong? Thank you in advance, I am super confused on this

Comment: May we see what the function "User.findOneAndUpdate();" does?
Might give some insights as to where the error may be.

Comment: Perhaps it never goes to any of the if statements e.g if(loadPlanning == data.email). Put print inside all the statement and see if it goes in. If it does, perhaps the findOneAndUpdate isn't working.

Comment: @unobatbayar, if the console.log() function works then it means the code goes into the if statements so the issue will be on the  findOneAndUpdate() function and that's why showing us that code will make it easier to debug and solve

Comment: @SiwokuAdeola yes

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few issues with the code you have. The `data` variable you got from the callback function and the `data` in `adminArray.forEach(function (data)` are two different values. The first is supposed to be an array which you assigned to `adminArray` and the second is an object in which you are trying to access the `email` property. This could be the cause of the issue you are having.

As a result of this, the line `User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {truckDriver: true});` would not work because there is a chance the value of `email` will be undefined in which case the `findOneAndUpdate` will be called with `{ email: undefined }`.

By the way, the `await` on this line `await User.find({ isVerified: true }, function (err, data) {...});` is not needed because you are dealing with a callback function.

I have refactored your code slightly, see below:

```js
router.post('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { truckDriver, truckNumber, admin, customer, loadPlanning } = req.body;

    const adminArray = await User.find({ isVerified: true });
    if (!adminArray) {
      return;
    }

    for (var key in req.body) {
      if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        adminArray.forEach(function (data) {
          if (truckDriver == data.email) {
            console.log(truckDriver);
            User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: data.email }, { truckDriver: true });
          }
          if (truckNumber == data.email) {
            console.log(truckNumber);
            User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: data.email }, { truckNumber: truckNumber });
          }
          if (admin == data.email) {
            console.log(admin);
            User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: data.email }, { admin: true });
          }
          if (customer == data.email) {
            console.log(customer);
            User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: data.email }, { customer: true });
          }
          if (loadPlanning == data.email) {
            console.log(loadPlanning);
            User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: data.email }, { loadPlanning: true });
          }
        });
      }
    }
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Your accounts have been processed!');
    res.redirect('/admin');
  }
  catch (e) {
    res.send('error_msg');
    console.log(e);
  };
});
```

Let me know if that works, in the case you see an error also let me know the error. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it using this

```
router.post('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const{ truckDriver, truckNumber, admin, customer, loadPlanning } = req.body;
        await User.find({isVerified: true}, function(err,data){
            adminArray = data;
            for(var key in req.body) {
                if(req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    adminArray.forEach(async (data, res) =>{
                        if(truckDriver == data.email){
                            await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {truckDriver: true});
                        }
                        if(truckNumber == data.email){
                            await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {truckNumber: truckNumber});
                        }
                        if(admin == data.email){
                            await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {admin: true});
                        }
                        if(customer == data.email){
                            await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {customer: true});
                        }
                        if(loadPlanning == data.email){
                            await User.findOneAndUpdate({email: data.email}, {loadPlanning: true});
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        })
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Your accounts have been processed!');
        res.redirect('/admin');
    }
    catch (e){
        res.send('error_msg');
        console.log(e);
    };
});
```

Thank you everyone for the help <3